# SQL DELETE except 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have duplicate data in my sql, i want to delete all `DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)` name but not `ID 129`...

```
ID
--
57
124
126
127
60
128
129

NAME
====

DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)
DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)
DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)
DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)
DiplomaInEnforcement&Compliance
DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)
DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)
```

i have tried delete from table where id=57 .... but i would to know the faster way to delete all but not the id i want to keep

Comment: What database are you using, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: You should post your code and ask for specific problem within that code.This question is not fit for SO

Comment: So far i manage to delete one by one to avoid delete the one i want to keep... delete from tablename where id=xx ... i was hopin there was faster way

Comment: Robbert has solve my problem thanks. u guys thanks for helpin me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty trivial. Not knowing your table name, I've substituted a generic one here.

```
Delete from table where 
NAME='DiplomaInOccupationalSafety&Health(Security)' and ID<>129
```

Comment: 0 row effected... but i can see the logic ther thanks alot

Comment: Workd for me. Check out this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27b76/3)

Comment: Wow.. yes it work on fiddle... idk why my sql server 2008 doesnt work..

Comment: WORKED!! i forget the ;